# Passing QModelIndex cross Thread queued connection

Tags: qt, threadpool, signals-slots, qmodelindex

```
WMIQuery::wmiquery(WMI::WMITable* table, const QString& query, WMI::ProgressIndicator* progressIndicator)
```

This is the Function signature. and I am calling it through `QtConcurrent::run`

```
QFuture<quint32> future = QtConcurrent::run(WMI::WMIQuery::wmiquery, _table, query);
```

The architecture is quite simple.
Expected number of rows that will be returned by the query is known.
query is ran parallelly and on each record fetch a row is added to  `table: WMI::WMITable*`
`WMI::WMITable` is a Simple QObject Table Data Structure .
it emits `rowsAboutToBeInserted(QModelIndex, int, int)` and `rowsInserted(QModelIndex, int, int)` upon row addition.

On the other hand `ProgressIndicator` in instantiated on main thread and the `table` is passed to its `ctor` . it gets the expected total number of rows from `WMI::WMIQuery::wmiquery()` through `ProgressIndicator::setRecordCount(quint64 count)`.
it has a slot `rowAdded()` which emits the progress out of 100 by doing some simple mathematics. In its ctor it connects

```
connect(_table, SIGNAL(rowsInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)), this, SLOT(rowAdded()));
```

What I think. as `WMI::WMIQuery::wmiquery()` i running on a different thread (on `QThreadPool`) this connection is a cross thread queued connection . am I correct ?

I am getting the following error at runtime

> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QModelIndex'
>   (Make sure 'QModelIndex' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)

What should I do ? as my `SLOT(rowAdded())` does not require the 3 arguments of `SIGNAL(rowsInserted(QModelIndex,int,int))` should I make another signal like `rowInserted()` and emit it whenever I am emitting `rowsInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)` and use this `SIGNAL` instead for this coinnection

You may ask why I am using model like signals like `rowsInserted(QModelIndex,int,int)` in the table data structure. cause I do also have a model that is connected to this table. which will also be updated row by row. however I think that is immater in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before emitting a signal across a thread boundary with a non-trivial argument type (like `QModelIndex`), you must first call this:

> ```
> qRegisterMetaType<QModelIndex>("QModelIndex");
> ```

That prepares Qt to be able to emit the signal across a thread boundary.

Normally you would do this in `main()` or somewhere that only runs once, **before** calling `emit`, but **after** your `QApplication` has been instantiated.

This is only necessary for types that are non-trivial. For example, a signal like this would **not** require you to call `qRegisterMetaType()`

> ```
> signals:
>    void mySignal(int foo, int bar);
> ```

But a signal like this **does** require `qRegisterMetaType()`:

> ```
> signals:
>    void mySignal(QModelIndex);
> ```

For more info, see the Qt docs here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType

Comment: Another option is to remove the `QModelIndex` and both `int`s from the signal you are emitting, since they are not received in the slot `rowAdded()` anyway.

Comment: Ya I've tried that way as I mentioned in the question. and it worked.

Comment: and also what are the extra overheads in `qRegisterMetaType<QModelIndex>("QModelIndex")` ? Should that solve that issue ? and is it a real way ? or a bad Hack ?

Comment: Using `qRegisterMetaType()` is the real way. It is not a hack. I have never noticed any overhead. It works great.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is rather late, but I wanted to be sure someone mentioned it: QModelIndex is not meant to be queued, for the same reason that it's not meant to be stored and used later in other ways.  That is, if the model changes before you use the QModelIndex, you will get undefined behavior.  If you need queued events with model indices, you should probably use QPersistentModelIndex.  Not really relevant to the original question, but may be of use to someone who lands here.